# Python: Scrapy "response.xpath" is not working

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, response

I have a Python 3 code using Scrapy. This is some part of the code:

```
import scrapy
...
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'example.com'
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
start_urls = [
    'http://www.example.com/1.html',
    'http://www.example.com/2.html',
]

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        image_link = self.get_image_link(response)
        try:
            item = response.xpath("//*[@id='theid1']").extract_first()
        except:
            item = response.xpath("//*[@id='theid2']").extract_first()
        ...
```

If I run the code as  normal, there will not be anything in the `item`, but if I put a breakpoint on this line:

```
image_link = self.get_image_link(response)
```

and run the code step by step then I have values in `item`.

Is there a timing issue I should be aware of? Is this related to asynchronous way Scrapy works? How can resolve this issue?

Comment: Impossible to say without more context, what is `get_image_link` doing exactly?

Comment: It is returning url address of the image on the scraped page

Comment: @PadraicCunningham do you have any suggestion for this? I really appreciate your help.